# Converting SQL to Arel - column [...] must appear in the GROUP BY clause

Tags: postgresql, arel

I have a working SQL query and I would like to convert it into an Arel, but I seem to keep on running into the same error.

**Working SQL:**

```
Order.find_by_sql(
    "SELECT COUNT(order_number) AS order_count,
    restaurant_id, date_part('month', date) AS date_month,
    date_part('year', date) AS date_year 
    FROM orders
    WHERE restaurant_id is not null
    GROUP BY(restaurant_id, date_part('month', date), date_part('year', date))
    ORDER BY date_part('year', date) desc, date_part('month', date) desc;"
  )
```

**Attempt 1** (not working)

```
orders = Order.arel_table

Order
    .where.not(restaurant_id: nil)
    .select(:restaurant_id)
    .select(:date)
    .select(Order.arel_table[:order_number].count.as('order_count'))
    .select(
        Arel::Nodes::NamedFunction.new('date_part', [Arel::Nodes.build_quoted('month'), :date]),
        Arel::Nodes::NamedFunction.new('date_part', [Arel::Nodes.build_quoted('year'), orders[:date]])
    )
    .group(
        :restaurant_id, 
        Arel::Nodes::NamedFunction.new('date_part', [Arel::Nodes.build_quoted('month'), orders[:date]]), 
        Arel::Nodes::NamedFunction.new('date_part', [Arel::Nodes.build_quoted('year'), orders[:date]])
    )
```

**Attempt 2** (not working)

```
orders = Order.arel_table
query = orders
      .where(orders[:restaurant_id].not_eq(nil))
      .project(
          orders[:restaurant_id],
          Order.arel_table[:order_number].count.as('order_count'),
          Arel::Nodes::NamedFunction.new('date_part', [Arel::Nodes.build_quoted('month'), orders[:date]]).as('date_month'),
          Arel::Nodes::NamedFunction.new('date_part', [Arel::Nodes.build_quoted('year'), orders[:date]]).as('date_year'),
      )
      .group(
          orders[:restaurant_id],
          Arel::Nodes::NamedFunction.new('date_part', [Arel::Nodes.build_quoted('month'), orders[:date]]),
          Arel::Nodes::NamedFunction.new('date_part', [Arel::Nodes.build_quoted('year'), orders[:date]])
      )
      .order(orders[:date].desc)
      .to_sql
Order.find_by_sql(query)
```

Both approaches result in the following error:

> PG::GroupingError: ERROR: column "orders.date" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function

The problem is that I don't want to group by date, but by month. Any tips on how to solve it?

I also originally tried `Arel::Nodes::NamedFunction.new('date_part', ['month', :date])` instead of `Arel::Nodes::NamedFunction.new('date_part', [Arel::Nodes.build_quoted('month'), orders[:date]])` but it resulted with the following:

> Unsupported argument type: String. Construct an Arel node instead.

Any help greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

So after hours of digging it turns out the big gotcha! of my problem was a `default_scope` set on my `Order` model - that's where sorting by `:date` was happening. In the end I decided to remove the default scope, use sorting where it was actually needed and what I was left it regarding my query was this:

```
orders = Order.arel_table
query = orders
  .where(orders[:restaurant_id].not_eq(nil))
  .project(
      orders[:restaurant_id],
      Order.arel_table[:order_number].count.as('order_count'),
      Arel::Nodes::NamedFunction.new('date_part', [Arel::Nodes.build_quoted('month'), orders[:date]]).as('date_month'),
      Arel::Nodes::NamedFunction.new('date_part', [Arel::Nodes.build_quoted('year'), orders[:date]]).as('date_year'),
  )
  .group(
      orders[:restaurant_id],
      Arel::Nodes::NamedFunction.new('date_part', [Arel::Nodes.build_quoted('month'), orders[:date]]),
      Arel::Nodes::NamedFunction.new('date_part', [Arel::Nodes.build_quoted('year'), orders[:date]])
  )
  .order(
      orders[:restaurant_id],
      Arel::Nodes::NamedFunction.new('date_part', [Arel::Nodes.build_quoted('year'), date]).desc,
      Arel::Nodes::NamedFunction.new('date_part', [Arel::Nodes.build_quoted('month'), date]).desc

  )
  .to_sql

Order.find_by_sql(query)
```

**Lesson learnt:** avoid `default_scope`s whenever possible. If you work alone, you're likely to forget you used it over time. If you work in a team, you might just cost somebody a full day of hair pulling.